# Arrowheads missing in drawing lines using `plot` command in `TikZ`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am using the `plot` command in `TikZ` to draw lines.  Why aren't the arrowheads drawn?  I use `<->` as an option for drawing the lines `y = (-4/3)x - 2` and `y = (3/4)x`, and I use `latex-latex` for drawing the axes.

Why is the line `y = (3/4)x` not drawn as a dashed line?

I would like to extend the axes by `12.5 pt`.  How would I do that?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%The unit circle centered at the origin is drawn. A line $\ell$ intersects the circle; an equation
%for it is 2x + (3/2)y = -3/2. An equation for the line k through the origin and perpendicular to $\ell$ is
%(-3/2)x + 2y = 0. The intersection of the two lines is P = (-12/25, -18/25). (The figure is
%magnified by 2.)
%
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O) circle (2);
%
%
\coordinate (P) at (-24/25,-18/25);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(-0.15,0)$){\textit{P}};
%
\draw plot [<->, domain=-2.75:0.5625] ({\x}, {(-4/3)*(\x) - 2});
%
\draw plot [<->, dashed, domain=-2.75:2.75] ({\x}, {(3/4)*\x});

%The axes are drawn.
\draw plot[latex-latex, domain=-2.75:2.75] ({\x}, {0}) node[below right]{\textit{x}};
\draw plot[latex-latex, domain=-2.75:2.75] ({0}, {\x}) node[above right]{\textit{y}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing arrowheads and absent dashing have the same cause: they are options that relate to the `\draw` macro, not the `plot` statement. You need `\draw [dashed] plot..`, and similar for the arrow head specification. To lengthen a line you can use `shorten <`/`shorten >` with a negative length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every plot/.append style={samples=2}] % as long as you only draw straight lines, 2 points are enough

%The unit circle centered at the origin is drawn. A line $\ell$ intersects the circle; an equation
%for it is 2x + (3/2)y = -3/2. An equation for the line k through the origin and perpendicular to $\ell$ is
%(-3/2)x + 2y = 0. The intersection of the two lines is P = (-12/25, -18/25). (The figure is
%magnified by 2.)
%
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O) circle (2);
%
%
\coordinate (P) at (-24/25,-18/25);
\draw[fill] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(-0.15,0)$){\textit{P}};
%
\draw [<->] plot [domain=-2.75:0.5625] ({\x}, {(-4/3)*(\x) - 2});
%
\draw [<->,dashed] plot [domain=-2.75:2.75] ({\x}, {(3/4)*\x});

%The axes are drawn.
\draw [latex-latex,shorten >=-12.5pt,shorten <=-12.5pt] plot[ domain=-2.75:2.75] ({\x}, {0}) node[below right]{\textit{x}};
\draw [latex-latex,shorten >=-12.5pt,shorten <=-12.5pt] plot[domain=-2.75:2.75] ({0}, {\x}) node[above right]{\textit{y}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would throw in [samples-2] for the plot options.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Good point, will edit.

Comment: Torbjørn T.  Thanks for the explanation.  Yes, the display is now what I wanted.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I did not use `samples=2` in my code, and the display that I got is the same as the one you got.  Isn't `samples=2` the default?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire 2 sample points is only useful for straight lines, the default is 25.

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as *Torbjørn T.* answer but with some 0ff-topic differences:

- coordinate axes are draw without `plot` macro
- coordinate `P` is determined by intersection

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, samples=]
%The unit circle centered at the origin is drawn. A line $\ell$ intersects the circle; an equation
%for it is 2x + (3/2)y = -3/2. An equation for the line k through the origin and perpendicular to $\ell$ is
%(-3/2)x + 2y = 0. The intersection of the two lines is P = (-12/25, -18/25). (The figure is
%magnified by 2.)
%
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (O) circle (2);
%
\draw[name path=A,<->]          plot[domain=-2.75:0.56252]  (\x, {(-4/3)*(\x) - 2});
\draw[name path=B,<->,dashed]   plot[domain=-2.75:2.75]     (\x, {(3/4)*\x});
% intersection
\draw[fill,
      name intersections={of=A and B, by={P}}] (-24/25,-18/25) 
            (P) circle (1.5pt) node[left] {$P$};
%The axes are drawn.

\draw [<->] (-2.75,0) -- (2.75,0) node[below right]{$x$};
\draw [<->] (0,-2.75) -- (0,2.75) node[above right]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]